# Aida tutorial error?

Tags: smalltalk, aida

Newbee question - I am trying to learn Aida from the 6.0 version for Dolphin Smalltalk using the tutorial for Pharao (I think). I know Smalltalk quite well but I am new to Web.

From AIDA tutorial:

**3. Registering a root domain object
After our ADemoAddressBook is prepared, we register its URL in Aida, so that it is accessible from web. In our workspace we evaluate:

AIDASite default register: book onUrl: '/addressbook'

But I get : register:onUrl: not understood, and I cannot find the method in the AIDASite class or in the image??
Really strange - what is the correct method to use ?

OBS OBS

Wow - I found it. Inspired by the french tutorial on the Wiki http://community.ofset.org/index.php/Aida_Tutorial.

The following works:

AIDASite default urlResolver defaultURL: '/addressbook' forObject: book

Comment: Aida on Dolphin is much older version while tutorial is always adapted to latest version. It helps if you look at [older versions of tutorial as well](http://www.aidaweb.si/tutorial?view=history)

Comment: Thanks but apart from that the example worked in Aida 6.0

Answer (score 1):

I don't know on Dolphin but on Pharo3.0, the code:

```
AIDASite default register: book onUrl: '/addressbook'
```

works fine.

Anyway this question is still marked as non answered whereas the author edit it with a solution and Janko said it's an issue of Aida's versions. So this answer is just to "close" this question.